# How to use trained model for another dataset in Sklearn's Random Forest Classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

**Update : Some "Terminology "**
Sample : row
features: columns
'labels' : classes for the prediction (one column among the features).

Basically I wonder : 
I have dataset1 and dataset2 identical in terms of shape and size. After training and testing with dataset1, I am using this model to predict dataset2. (Number of features are also same).

**If I predict all the items in the dataset2 , accuracy is close to dataset1 test results. But If I pick 1 item for each class from dataset2, accuracy is around 30%. How it is possible that full dataset2 accuracy is drastically different than the "subsampled" dataset2?**

I am using RandomForestClassifier.

I have a data set with 200K sample (rows) having around 90 classes. After Training and testing, accuracy is high enough (around ~96%).

Now since I have a trained model, I am using another different database (again with 200 K samples and 90 classes) to make predictions.

If I submit all samples from this second database, accuracy is close enough to training accuracy (around ~92% ).

But If I select 90 samples (one from each class) from this second database accuracy is not what I have expected. (around ~30%)

```
.... data preprocessing is done.

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=nestimators, bootstrap=False, 
class_weight=None, criterion='entropy',
        max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
        min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,

        min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_jobs=6,
        oob_score=False, random_state=np.random.seed(1234), verbose=0, warm_start=False)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)    

from sklearn import metrics
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

and accuracy is around ~96%.

Now I am using this trained model with a new database (identical in shape) :

```
df2=pd.read_csv("newdata.csv", low_memory=False, skipinitialspace=True, na_filter=False)
features=['col1','col2','col3','col4']
Xnew=df2[features].values
ynew=df2['labels'].values  # Labels
y_prednew=clf.predict(Xnew)
```

Accuracy is above ~90%. Close to first database accuracy. But

If I filter this new data set for 1 sample for each class with this :

```
df2=pd.read_csv("newdata.csv", low_memory=False, skipinitialspace=True, na_filter=False)

samplesize=1
df2=df2.sample(frac=1)
df2=df2.groupby('labels')
df2=df2.head(samplesize).reset_index(drop=True)

features=['col1','col2','col3','col4']
Xnew=df2[features].values
ynew=df2['labels'].values  # Labels
y_prednew=clf.predict(Xnew)
```

...
accuracy is ~35%. But if I do not filter this new data and submit it to the model accuracy is above ~90%.

First and second data sets are identical in term of shape. If I give all samples from the second data set to this trained model, accurayc is close to the first dataset test results. But If I filter it for 1 sample from each class, accuracy is ~30%.

I dont know where did I make mistake.

Comment: Are you sure there is a mistake in this? If I use sample size = 1 instead of sample size = 200K, I would not be surprised to obtain low scores. By "classes" you mean `features`, right?

Comment: I say "classes" for predictions. features are my inputs : col1 col2 col3 etc.

Comment: Basically if I use this trained model for another database with the same shape, accuracy is what I have expected. But if I subsample this second database (1 sample for eac class = 90 sample instead of 200K samples) accuracy is around 30%

Comment: You make 90 different predictions with one model? How many features do you use for training then? I am still not sure if this is really a problem of the code. No one guarantees to you that the one sample you draw per "class" (whatever that is, I still don't quite relate to your terminology) can really be predicted by the model with the same accuracy as the whole data set.

Comment: Yes data set has 90 different "classes". Features are around 256~. The part I dont get is if I use second database with all 200K samples for predictions , model accuracy is reasonable. But if I subsample this dataset to 1 sample from each class (which means 90 samples in total) , accuracy is around 35%

Comment: Following your sample code, I feel like there are some missing parts after checking with the new data set. How does your one sample find its way to `Xnew` and `y_prednew`?

Comment: Xnew basically has 90 samples. 1 sample for each class.  By "sample" I mean "row" I hope it clearifies.

Comment: Sorry, I mean: `y_prednew=clf.predict(Xnew)` in your last block of code. You update `df2` (picking one sample per class), but then how do you change `Xnew`?

Comment: Last block of the code is only run if I want to subsample this second dataset and prediction is done afterwards. I have updated the code for clearification.

Comment: Ok. Well, still after your update ... I don't see anything wrong with your sklearn implementation. I cannot speak for how you draw samples (don't know about pandas, I'm afraid). If I were to debug the code, I would run it sample per sample and observe the scores. If they are all low -> something's wrong with the model. If they vary a lot -> some samples can be predicted better than others.

Comment: I have also iterate over this "subsampling" section many times and the accuracy was always low. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You are using the exact same features for the prediction as for the training, right? Same number and same features? You do not take random features, but random samples?

Comment: Yes for the first dataset (during the training of the model, it is also divided for  training and testing), features (columns in data dataset) does not change.

Second dataset is totally different dataset (but same in shape and size) and nothing to do with this training and testing of the model. I am using it to see "real" accuracy of the model.

Comment: Shape is one thing, but features are the other. Let's say you learn a robot (RF) to distinguish between bananas and strawberries. Features could be size, color, taste and sugar content. Now you show your model 200K fruits of different classes (different types of bananas/strawberries, e.g. from different countries). You save some of that fruits and the model is able to classify correctly in 90% of all cases. Now you take one banana from Indonesia, one from Panama, [...] and ask the model to predict if it's a banana or a strawberry. But you must still provide size, color, taste and sugar content

Comment: and you need to make sure that these features belong to the right label ("banana")

Comment: Number of features do not change and used in both dataset1 and dataset2. After training and testing with dataset1, I am using this model to predict dataset2. If I predict all the items in the dataset2 , accuracy is close to dataset1. But If I pick 1 item for each class from dataset2, accuracy is around 30%. How it is possible that full dataset2 accuracy is drastically different than the "subsampled" dataset2?

Comment: It's not, as long as the sample you draw is representative to the whole set of samples. Does it work when you only take ONE sample instead of one per class (run it multiple times to get a feeling for how different the outcome is for different input samples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the code seems OK. It's hard to know but I would hazard a guess that the classes aren't equally represented in the dataset (at least the second, perhaps also the first), and the more dominant classes are more accurately identified.

The classic example is some extremely imbalanced binary classification task where 99% of the samples are positive. By always predicting positive you can get 99% accuracy, but a sample of 1 datapoint for each class would have 50% accuracy (and  while out-of-context the accuracy might seem good, the model isn't very useful).

I would recommend examining the class frequencies, and also using other metrics (see [precision](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html), [recall](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html) and [f1](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html)) with the appropriate `average` parameter to more accurately assess your model's performance.

To summarise, a 90%+ accuracy on the entire dataset and 30% accuracy on a sample of 1 datapoint for each class aren't necessarily conflicting, e.g. if the classes aren't balanced in the dataset.

Edit: In short what I'm trying to say is that it could be you're experiencing the [Accuracy Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_paradox).

Comment: Thanks for your time for answering my question.

I can not get the fact that If I submit all the items from dataset2 to the trained model, accuracy is above 90%. But if I select 1 sample for each class (90 samples in total) from dataset2 accuracy is around 30%. I have also iteratively select 1 sample for each class and tested the model for 20 times. Everytime accuracy is around 30%.

Comment: Did you examine class frequencies? Suppose you have 90 classes, `c1`, `c2`, ... `c90`. Also suppose that about 92% of the samples are `c42`, and the model almost always predicts `c42`. Then for the entire dataset your accuracy would be about 92%, while for a sample of one datapoint for each class you would have accuracy around `1/90` =~ 1.1%. So what you're describing could be explained by a less severe instance of such an imbalance (though ofc this isn't the only explanation).

Comment: In short what I'm saying is that it could be you're experiencing the Accuracy Paradox - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_paradox

Comment: Thanks again for your time.  The scores are as shown below after the training of the model. (dataset1)

f1_score - Macro : 0.5922192285564758
f1_score - Micro : 0.9633939516061324
f1_score - weighted : 0.9585028022207839

precision_score - Macro : 0.851618083669928
precision_score - Micro : 0.9633939516061324
precision_score - Weighted : 0.963924354819605

Comment: Basically how should I measru my accuracy then ? Class frequency is very diverse in my data. Some classes are dominant.

Comment: Thanks for this usefull answer. I found out that, If I train my model with dataset1 with almost equal number of items from each class, dataset2 accuracy with 1 sample from each class accuracy peaked. I am marking this as an aswer.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: In your results `f1_macro` being around 60% hints that some classes aren't accurately predicted. How you measure performance is up to you: if all classes are equally important, maybe measuring accuracy is OK. In textbook examples for cancer classification, positives are very rare (say 1%) but obviously false negatives are much more "dangerous" than false positives, in which case recall is the important metric. You can even construct a "cost matrix" to specify exactly how bad each type of misclassification is.